# Error: Void function return value is used

Tags: javascript, symfony, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, stimulusjs

I use Stimulus in Symfony 5 and when I use this code in my Stimulus controller, PhpStorm shows an error.

How can I fix this?

```
import {Controller} from 'stimulus';
import {index} from "../js/index";
export default class extends Controller{
    connect(){
        const index1 = index();
    }
}
```

> Error: Void function return value is used

My `index()` function is:

```
export function index(){
...
}
```

Comment: Does index return anything? If not, you can just remove `const index1 = `, because it will not set anything when you call `index()` anyway, so there is nothing to assign

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
import {Controller} from 'stimulus';
import Index from "../js/index";
export default class extends Controller{
    connect(){
        const index1 = new Index;
        index1.index();
    }
}
```

And use this for your index class:

```
export default class Index {
    index(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler replace `const index1 = index();` with `index();`? Why is a class necessary?

Comment: @FelixKling When you create a class and want to use in other class, you need to use `const index1 = new Index` .

Comment: All I see that the user wants to call a function, not actually use a class. But maybe I don't understand what this is all about.

Comment: @BahmanMD please can you explain why yours works?